# Upgrade Oracle DB from 12C to 19C with minimum downtime

Tags: oracle-12c, oracle-19c, dataguard, goldengate

We are planning to apply the below steps -->

1. Export Live DB setup on the Oracle version 12C
2. Import on the new DB setup on version 19C
3. At this point, V12, and V19 schema structures will be exactly the same (till here we tested and it works fine)
4. Add a new data guard in the DB running on Oracle v12 to point to the upgrade DB setup on version 19C
5. **Once the data guard is ready and DB import completes, we point the data guard to the upgrade DB and wait for sync complete**

Can you please review and confirm if this is achievable?

At this time we plan to use Data guard and if it is not possible then we will use the golden gate.

Comment: This is a complex project. You should make a proof of concept. So  create a 12c database an upgrade it the way you intend.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using DataGuard to do 1, 2, 3 & 4, rather than doing it "by hand".  It should be "happy" pushing changes "uphill", but going the other way probably won't work, so you need to be certain when you go to cut-over.  Create a Database /Service/ and offer it only from the Primary Database.  That way, a FAILOVER configuration in the TNS Naming file will support a clean cut-over.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using the physru_v3.sh shell-script available from Oracle support? It is using a transient logical standby database to upgrade an instance without downtime. cf.
[Mike Dietrich](https://mikedietrichde.com/2018/05/09/transient-logical-standby-rolling-upgrades-overview/)
and clarify with the Oracle licence team, whether using a logical standby for DB upgrade is OK in case you just need it for an upgrade.